# Connect a device on main network to device on subnetwork/subnet through LAN

Tags: networking, router, lan

I want to play Borderlands 2 over LAN with my brother but the game isn't detecting anyone's session.

My PC is connected with an ethernet cable (into the wall), so it is directly under the modem's network. The connection is: modem-->ethernet-->my pc. My PC's IP address is: 192.168.70.xxx

My brother's laptop though is connected via WIFI through a router. His connection is: modem-->ethernet-->router-->wifi-->his laptop. His laptop's IP address is: 192.168.0.xxx

Is it somehow possible for both our devices to have the same IP configuration of 192.168.yy.xxx, create a route from my PC to the router he's connected to or, perhaps, some other solution is possible?

I am not that experienced in networking and I only know basic stuff from Minecraft servers.

Another thing I tested was trying to ping each other's IP addresses. Pinging his IP address (192.168.0.xxx) from my PC (192.168.70.xxx) did not work, but him pinging my PC's address from his laptop worked.

Any help or resources that I could look into would be really appreciated.

Comment: You either need to change the Wireless subnet if you can. Ask your ISP.  Alternatively, install a router of your own on the Ethernet port and set up your own "one" subnet network. I do this here.

Comment: Is your PC really connected to router's WAN port? Why?

Comment: @gronostaj 
I just use ethernet which goes into the wall. I am assuming that directly goes into the modem because when I open 192.168.70.1 to check the settings, I can see the connected devices which are my PC + the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by turning the router into a "bridge". This made all devices connected to that router under the modem's network, all with an IP of 192.168.70.xxx which made it possible for my PC to communicate with the laptop.

For anyone checking this in the future, you should search online about turning your specific router into bridge mode.

In my case I had a d-link router and I was able to do it by first going to its settings (192.168.0.1). I disabled both DHCP and UPNP and changed the router's IP address from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.70.xxx (just like my modem's network). This turned it into a "bridge" and all connected devices through the router now had an IP address of 192.168.70.xxx and appeared connected directly to the modem.

Also the Ethernet cable from the modem/wall to your router should go into the LAN plug not the "internet" plug on your router.